# WPF: Save connection string programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project, and I am trying to save a new connection string programmatically using this code:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(connectionStringName, "SERVER=localhost;USERID=root;PASSWORD=****;DATABASE=" + databaseName, "MySQL"));
```

But I get the following exception:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: The configuration is read only.

I did some googling but I didn't find a workaround to this problem.

Comment: check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)